# How to configure log4js in protractor

Tags: protractor, log4js-node

Can anyone suggest how to configure log4js in protractor config. When i use

```
var log4js = require('log4js');var logger = log4js.getLogger();
```

im able to print the logs in the console. But i want to configure the log4js to get the logs to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link

1. install log4j with npm
2. configure in conf.js - appender section
3. declare in main.js / main entry of program
4. add logging in scripts

   var log4js = require('log4js');

   log4js.loadAppender('file');
   log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file('data.log'), 'logs');
   var logger = log4js.getLogger('logs');
   logger.info('Started   testcases ');

http://247knowledge.blogspot.in/2014/07/logger-in-protractor-e2e-testing.html